# Is there a programmable USB board with (momentary) toggle switches?

Tags: gaming

What I'm looking for is something like a flight controller panel with customizable (makros) toggle switches similar to the ones found in airplanes.
[image]

Not sure if this is in scope but I found nothing on google...

Comment: This would be a great hobby project, to make something like this... At least on the electronics/MCU side.

Comment: @JanDorniak yes, thats probably what I'll do if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I think ST has mouse HID examples for the F0 discovery

Comment: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkYyRSAV/usb-device-hid-keyboard-example see first reply

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/NUCLEO-F722ZE/497-17093-ND/6622019